# JQuery - Unfamiliar notation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am modifying a javascript file in which they have used the following code. Does anyone know what this does / where it is documented / etc. It appears it is creating an anchor node and giving it the inner html of "Back", but I'm not sure how it works or what it's capabilities are, as I need to add various attributes to the link:

```
$("<a id=>").html("Back");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery is just being forgiving.  Normally, the code would look like this, instead:

```
$('<a/>').html("Back");
```

Which means, create an `a` element and set its inner HTML to "Back".  You can chain some attribute assignments directly after:

```
$('<a/>')
    .html('Back');
    .attr('id', 'your-id');
```

Comment: It is also possible to set the attributes during element creation, e.g. `$('<a/>', {html:'Back',id:'your-id'});`.

Answer (score 2):

This code is indeed creating an anchor element:

```
<a id="">Back</a>
```

You can add attributes using the "attr" function, like so:

```
$("<a id=>").html("Back").attr('href', myUrl);
```

Alternatively, you can add the attributes directly in the markup:

```
$("<a id='myId' href='url'>").html("Back");
```

Answer (score 1):

It is creating an anchor element, but it hasn't appended it to anything, what you would normally do, is either:

```
$("body").append($("<a>").html("Back").attr("target", "_blank"));
```

(as an example), or even:

```
$("<a>").html("Back").attr("target", "_blank").appendTo($("body"));
```

Because it is a jQuery object, you can continue chaining methods on it to build it up how you want to.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just some bothched HTML being passed to the factory.  Should result in a jQuery collection holding one anchor element which is not yet in the DOM and which has an empty id attr and contains the text "Back":

```
<a id="">Back</a>
```